# Cant install OpenGApps on Lineage OS

Tags: lineageos

I recently installed Lineage OS on a Nexus 6, using TWRP, followed by OpenGApps installation which crashed at 4%. So I started phone, switched off went to TWRP again, tried installation same problem. I used aroma for arm 32-bit. Any idea whats happening?

**Lineage OS**  : `lineage-14.1-20170331-nightly-shamu-signed`

**OpenGApps**   : `open_gapps-arm-7.1-aroma-20170405`

There are no Google Apps on the phone, the Lineage is working fine (or I say brilliant) but sigh, no Play Services no other apps.

Comment: `open_gapps-arm-7.1-aroma-20170405` is broken,  I repeat this build is broken. I used stock version and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open_gapps-arm-7.1-aroma-20170405` is broken, I repeat this build is broken. I used stock version and it worked. Also this build of Lineage OS has connectivity issues, you may face extremely slow downloads on WiFi (tested on Nexus 6 shamu).

Comment: I would like to get someone else confirmation about the issue here. How are  more recent releases doing?